# Find volume of rev using washer AND shell

Tags: calculus

Volume of revolution for the region bounded by $y= x^2$, $y=0$, $x=1$, $x=2$ about the line $x=4$.
The shell method is straightforward and I get the correct answer of $67 \pi /6$.

However, working this via disk-washer appears to need 2 separate regions - one from $0$ to $1$, and the second from $1$ to $4$. I don’t get the same answer, instead getting $11 \pi /3$.

Can someone assist with the disk-washer method for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to set up  two integrals.

The bottom part  is $$\int _0^1 \pi (9-4) dy$$

and the top part is $$ \int _1^4 \pi ((4-\sqrt y)^2 -4) dy$$

Comment: That’s exactly what I did set up but did NOT get same answer. Shouldn’t answer be same?

Comment: Via shell method I get the book answer = 67pi/6

Comment: I’m assuming you ADD those 2 integrals’ answers

Comment: Yes you add the two integrals to get the total volume.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

The washer integral is

$$\pi\int_0^1 (3^2-2^2)dy 
+ \pi \int_1^4 [(4-\sqrt y)^2- (4-2)^2]dy$$
$$=5\pi +\frac{37\pi}6=\frac{67\pi}6$$